# create a table that shows all Blogs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Interview Question:-

Hi 
   I am a beginner in rails.I went for a interview and was asked the following question:-

Suppose you have the following set of models and relationships

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :blogs
   # Properties:  name
end

class Blog << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  has_one :image
  # Properties:  title, body
end

class Image << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  # Properties:  image_file_path
end
```

Suppose you want to create a table that shows all Blogs. The columns of the table are the blog title, the author name and the blog image.

Write an ActiveRecord query that will pull the list of @blogs necessary to display this table. Can you do this such that under the covers `no more then 3 SQL statements` are generated? How about no more than 1?

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use the following query to get all blogs.

@blogs = Blog.find(:all, include: :project, include: :image)

In view..
   @blogs.each do |blog|
 blog.title
 blog.author.name
 blog.image.image_path

end

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understood your question correctly, but to get the list of all the blogs, you would just do:

```
@blogs = Blog.all
```

You can try something like that on the Rails console and it will show you the corresponding SQL query which is simply

```
SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs"
```

There's a guide on the Rails site which goes over Active Record querying if you'd like to take a look: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects